# Streamer/Ribbon Difference Question

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, idioms, teaching-aid

Just a different question but it's bugging me, I need an answer.

I used to come from France to the USA when i was a boy to visit my family, and to my great annoyance (they thought it would suit my blond hair) and embarrassment my two American female cousins managed to put me in a dress and attach something to my hair. I can't figure out the name of what they attached to my hair back then but I think it's called either a ribbon or a streamer and it was in American flags.

Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Streamer carries the implication that it is long and narrow.  Typically, it would be attached to a child's bicycle handle to catch the wind and stream.

It is a type of ribbon.  But, ribbons can be wide, flat, short, etc.

What you are describing being put in your hair is a ribbon.  When someone ties something of that nature into their hair, it is described as a ribbon.

In summary, not all ribbons are streamers, but all streamers are ribbons.

[Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/streamer)